# When is Genius Yield going to release its PAB?

Tags: untagged

I know that GeniusYield announced some time ago that they would make their PAB open-source.

Does somebody know when they are going to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like they just announce it! It's out now...more at https://atlas-app.io/